# Estimation of a combinatorial sum when $n$ is large.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Suppose $c,t$ are such that, $0< c< 1$ constant and $cn\leq t \leq n$.
I want to have an estimation of

$\sum _{i=0}^{cn} {cn\choose {i}}{(1-c)n \choose t-i} 2^{t-i}$

when n goes to infinity.

I have no idea to do that.Is there any hint?

Can I bound it by $2^{c'n}$ for some $0<c'< \log_2(3)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's simple. As you move from $i$'th term to the $(i+1)$'th one, the first binomial coefficient multiplies by $cn-i\over i$, the second by $t-i\over(1-c)n-t+i$, and the whole term by ${cn-i\over i}\cdot{t-i\over(1-c)n-t+i}\cdot{1\over2}$. Now, when $i\approx1$, the terms are growing, then at some point the ratio becomes smaller than 1 and they start to decrease. Find $i$ at which the ratio crosses 1 (that requires solving a quadratic equation), then find the corresponding term, and probably substitute all factorials with their Stirling approximations, if you prefer them that way. That would be the maximum term, and also the lower bound for the whole sum. Now multiply it by $cn$. That would be the upper bound.